# How create plugin for moodle for get user by option field with rest request

Tags: rest, plugins, moodle

Moodle have common rest request core_user_get_user but he works with defined field: id, fullname, email etc. Can I create a plugin to pull a user by optional fields, for example skype?

I try use core_user_get_user with criteria[0][key]=skype&criteria[0][value]=value, but its doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a web service plugin

The developer documentation is here

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external/writing-a-service

To get you started, see the Moodle functions in `/user/externallib.php`

There are 3 existing Moodle functions

- `get_users_by_field` - the main code
- `get_users_by_field_parameters` - incoming parameters
- `get_users_by_field_returns` - return parameters

Then create a local plugin for your new web service

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/local

At a minimum, you will need the following files

```
/local/mypluginname/version.php
/local/mypluginname/lang/en/local_mypluginname.php
```

A services file to tell Moodle where your web service code is

```
/local/mypluginname/db/services.php
```

And your web service code in a class

```
/local/mypluginname/classes/external/get_user_by_custom_field.php
```

The class will need 3 functions

- `execute` - the main code
- `execute_parameters` - incoming parameters
- `execute_return` - return parameters

See https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external/writing-a-service for further details