# Accessing Moodle via Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, moodle

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

I am currently programming a python script that should download feedback files from courses in Moodle,

The script can login successfully into moodle. But for every GET request it redirects me to a certain page that was not requested.

```
import time
import requests
import configparser
import bs4


moodle_url = "https://moodle.uni-bielefeld.de/"


def login(session, id, password):

    def get_relay_state_saml(html):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
        divs = soup.findAll("div")
        divs = divs[0]
        relay_tag = divs.contents[1]
        saml_tag = divs.contents[3]
        relay_value = relay_tag['value']
        saml_value = saml_tag['value']
        return {'RelayState': str(relay_value), 'SAMLResponse': str(saml_value)}

    response = session.get('https://moodle.uni-bielefeld.de/auth/shibboleth/index.php')

    # select university
    payload_select = {
        'user_idp': 'https://shibboleth.uni-bielefeld.de/idp/shibboleth',
        'Select': 'Select'
    }
    # redirect to login page
    response_select = session.post(response.url, data=payload_select)
    # print(response_select.text)
    # login form
    payload_login = {
        'j_username': id,
        'j_password': password,
        '_eventId_proceed': ''
    }

    response_login = session.post(response_select.url, data=payload_login)
    # print(response_login.url)
    # print(response_login.text)

    payload_accept = {
        '_shib_idp_consentIds': 'givenname',
        '_eventId_proceed': 'Accept'
    }

    response_logged = session.post(response_login.url, data=payload_accept)
    # print(response_logged.url)
    # print(response_logged.text)
    # print(get_relay_state_saml(response_logged.text))

    payload_saml = get_relay_state_saml(response_logged.text)
    # print(payload_saml)

    response_moodle = session.post("https://moodle.uni-bielefeld.de/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST", data=payload_saml)
    # print(response_moodle.url)
    # print(response_moodle.text)


def check_for_new_feedback(session):

    def get_uebungsblatter(html):
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

        # print(soup)
        blaetter = []
        # retrieve all
        return blaetter
    # this is the part where i always get redirected to the profile editing page
    response = session.get(moodle_url)

    blaetter = get_uebungsblatter(response.text)


def scraper():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    student_id = config['config']['student_id']
    password = config['config']['password']
    mail = config['config']['mail']
    last_sent = int(config['config']['last_sent'])
    wait_between_calls = int(config['config']['wait_between_calls'])

    with requests.session() as session:
        login(session, student_id, password)
        while True:
            check_for_new_feedback(session)
            time.sleep(60*wait_between_calls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper()
```

After some research and reverse engineering I found out that by clicking a certain course using a browser, it sends a GET request with the correct link with the course id.
Shortly after. It sends a POST request to this URL

> https://moodle.uni-bielefeld.de/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey=PWSjDeVJNC&info=core_courseformat_get_state

given this Payload

```
[{"index":0,"methodname":"core_courseformat_get_state","args":{"courseid":2891}}]
```

I have tried to sending those requests to get to the page I want, but it keeps redirecting me to THAT page.

If someone would be able to help or at least understand what is going on here and tell me what is wrong with the code, I would be happy to hear from you.

Much Thanks in Advance,

Another stackoverflower

Answer (score 0):

> this is the part where i always get redirected to the profile editing page

In Moodle, there can be required fields for a user - these can be added at any time as custom fields

If they are empty, then the user is redirected to edit their profile after login

There are also permissions checks, so some pages might not display as expected or you might be redirected again

**Web services**

To access data externally, you should use web services

It's a bit of a nuisance to set up, but will be a lot easier to use once it is set up

Go to Site admin > Server > Web services > Overview

Or direct to http://yourwebsite.com/admin/settings.php?section=webservicesoverview

This will display a check list for setting up web services

**API documentation**

For a list of existing web service functions, go to

Site admin > Server > Web services > Api documentation

Or direct to http://yourmoodlesite.com/admin/webservice/documentation.php

Depends on your requirements but there are a few feedback functions there

**Custom web service**

If you can't find an existing function that works for you, then you can also create your own web service function

See

[How create plugin for moodle for get user by option field with rest request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973391/how-create-plugin-for-moodle-for-get-user-by-option-field-with-rest-request/75975931#75975931)